# Where is the line drawn between "you're saying the name wrong" and "this is how it's called where I'm from"?

Tags: pronunciation

For example, if you say New Orleans like "New Orleens" it's considered wrong, instead of "New Orlins" (Orleans is pronounced different in France though), or Iran like "I ran" is wrong, instead of "Ear on". But then people have names for other places all over, like Germany or Allemagne, instead of Deutschland, which would have their own pronunciation. An even closer example would be France, pronounced like "Fronce" for the locals, and closer to "Frants" for Americans. Maybe this is protested in France, I'm not sure. Or Greenwich, UK vs. USA (I wonder if each says the other should be pronounced like their own). But when does pronunciation of somewhere else become wrong instead of their own way of saying it?

Comment: Vaguely. Considering UK place names, many well known ones are pronounced differently to their spelling (Leicester — Lester); some lesser known ones are pronounced differently only locally (Hunstanton — Hunston); and some reasonably well-known ones have a different pronunciation locally (Marylebone — Marly-bone vs Mara-la-bone). IMO it's better not to say "you are saying it wrong" but look for an opportunity to say it right.

Comment: Any answer is surely going to be opinion-based: there are few authorities over the English language dictating pronunciation. I find it difficult to know what to do when a proper name is pronounced in a typically non-British way ('Columbia Glacier'; 'Fly Geyser' ...). But then 'Arkansas' (the river) has distinct pronunciations **required** by certain states.

Comment: I would think saying the answer is opinion based or too vague to say is an answer itself.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on [SE Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) if the question isn't about the actual pronunciation but on how you tell someone they are saying the name incorrectly (for the region they are in).

Comment: I'm not asking how to deal with people on pronunciation. I'm asking for how 'wrong' or 'colloquial' is determined. If the answer is, there isn't a good answer, that's an answer.

Comment: 'Wrong' as in place name or in politics? The question asks *Where is the line drawn between "you're saying the name wrong" and "this is how it's called where I'm from"?* How you tell them is personal politics, not English Usage.

Comment: I don't think pronunciation is politics. If you pronounce things wrong in school, you are corrected, same for any word.

Comment: It's not the pronunciation that is politics (unless you deliberately mispronounce to cause offence). Please the question you asked – which is in **the title**. VTC for lack of clarity as to what is being asked.

Comment: I don't think. you're understanding the question. Like how is pronunciation determined, which is the right way. If everyone in an area says "new orleens" what determined that they were all saying it wrong, as opposed to the people all saying "frants", which I don't think is corrected.

Comment: If you do understand, you can edit the question to make it more clear for you

Comment: There is no 'right way' to pronounce anything. There are only regional dialects. Sorry, I can't edit the question: only you know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Like I said, pronunciation gets corrected in schools. If you say Iran wrong and claim it's due to your regional dialect, you still get corrected.

Comment: Do they also correct your pronuncation of 'Paris' and 'Moscow'?

Comment: No, that's what I'm talking about. Why is that not corrected, but New Orleans is.

Comment: If you think there's a line, where do you draw it?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Clearly Paris isn't pronounced like the locals would, but people get corrected when not pronouncing New Orleans like the locals, though many people don't. Why is that?

Comment: The question was clear enough for people to answer. Ppl quick to hate.

Comment: You are confusing two different issues - the fact that countries and places have different names in different languages (Deutschland/Germany/Allemagne) and that the names of some places are pronounced by locals in a way that is non-intuitive _to speakers of the same language_.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding.  I just said that to say people have their own way to call places, and how do we know it wasn't that instead of a non-intuitive way to say it, causing mispronounciation. It sounds like tradition is the best answer so far, no rules otherwise. Like how do we know we aren't saying Paris wrong, and this is just how english is supposed to say it. How is that determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no rules in this case, only tradition.

Just ask a New Yorker, who will agree that HEW-stǝn is a city in Texas, but will insist that HOW-stǝn is a street in Manhattan.

No one knows for sure why England should be *Angleterre* in French, nor Italy *Włochy* in Polish.

But: it's all great fun, if you ask me.

Comment: To be clear, Angleterre is like a translation of England to french. but yeah, why did they do that, though french may do that more than others.

Comment: @user14094230: Rather, it's a calque. So what. It's still fun.

Answer (score 0):

### It's a fuzzy line that can be very much political

There's always some tension between "say it the way the locals say it" and "say it the way my people say it". Whether variant pronunciations are "okay" or not is often a political question that's deeply influenced by history, and can become fraught when the people involved have wildly different degrees of socio-political influence.

Most of us are pretty forgiving about people saying a place-name weirdly when it's a result of an accent. When a coworker from India says the name of the city I live in and it comes out with some odd vowel sounds, I'm not going to call him out on it. He's doing a lot better in English than I would in Hindi. But also, people like me are the dominant social and political force in my city. It doesn't bother us if somebody says the name weird.

That's not necessarily the case everywhere, though. When the 'common' name for your city, country, geographical feature, or people-group is something mutated by people from the other side of the world who didn't even listen that closely when your people told them the name, it's pretty easy to see why that would be a problem. The extreme end of that scale is probably where your home is fully colonized by people from somewhere else, and the features of your language have been stripped out of the names everyone uses. There's a point where "different pronunciation" shades into "completely renamed it", and there isn't a bright line distinction between them.

To take an example from the recent news look at the capital of Ukraine, Kyiv or Kiev. It has been called "key-EV" by absolutely everyone for decades. But that's not really how the locals say it; that's the way it's pronounced *in Russian*. Since Russia has long been the dominant political power in the area, everyone sort of fell in line with that way of saying the name.  But now that name is suddenly a very political question -- calling the place Key-ev is as much as saying Russia has a *right* to own the place and call it as they will, so there's a strong effort in many places to avoid that and at least try to say it the way the locals do, which is something closer to Kyeev.

For most places, it probably doesn't matter if you say a name "right" or not. Sometimes it does, and reasonable people can disagree on where the line is. My personal rule is that if a local (or somebody who should know the right way) corrects me, I'll accept the correction, because it's clearly important to them. But communication is also important, so even if I know Reims in France should be said like "rhem", I'm not going to say it that way to my parents, because they won't know what I'm saying unless I say it phonetically.

Comment: That is a good example of when it can be political sometimes.